# Remove class when clicked away

Tags: javascript, html, css

Been struggling with a problem for a few days now. So, when I can't figure it out myself I went to the forum. Hope you guys can help me figure it out.

For the navbar, the items will light up when the user reached the section. That's all good. But when I scroll down and click away the item still lights up. I guess the observer doesn't remove the class. I can't figure out how I could do this.

I made a codepen to illustrate the code and the problem. Hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

https://codepen.io/tijmenjacobs/pen/wvdeaow

```js
const checkForSections = () => {
  const optionsSections = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "-350px -150px",
    threshold: .9
  };

  const addHighlightClass = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    const id = entry.target.getAttribute("id");

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      document
        .querySelector(`.navbar__link[href="#${id}"]`)
        .parentElement.classList.add("highlight");
    } else {
      document
        .querySelector(`.navbar__link[href="#${id}"]`)
        .parentElement.classList.remove("highlight");
    }
  };
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(addHighlightClass, optionsSections);
  // Track sections
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section[id]")).map((section) => {
    observer.observe(section);
  });
};

checkForSections();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar__list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar__item {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.navbar__link,
.navbar__link:visited {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar__link:hover,
.navbar__link:active,
.navbar__link:visited:hover,
.navbar__link:visited:active {
  color: red;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section h2 {
  color: #bada55;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar__list">
    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="#home" class="navbar__link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="#about" class="navbar__link">About</a></li>
    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="#contact" class="navbar__link">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>
  <section id="home">
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <h2>About</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of only checking the first `entry` with `const [entry] = entries;` you can iterate through all entries and update accordingly.

```
const addHighlightClass = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const id = entry.target.getAttribute("id");

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      document
        .querySelector(`.navbar__link[href="#${id}"]`)
        .parentElement.classList.add("highlight");
    } else {
      document
        .querySelector(`.navbar__link[href="#${id}"]`)
        .parentElement.classList.remove("highlight");
    }
  })
};
```

Edited snippet:

```js
const checkForSections = () => {
  const optionsSections = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "-350px -150px",
    threshold: .9
  };

  const addHighlightClass = (entries) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      const id = entry.target.getAttribute("id");

      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        document
          .querySelector(`.navbar__link[href="#${id}"]`)
          .parentElement.classList.add("highlight");
      } else {
        document
          .querySelector(`.navbar__link[href="#${id}"]`)
          .parentElement.classList.remove("highlight");
      }
    })
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(addHighlightClass, optionsSections);
  
  // Track sections
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section[id]")).map((section) => {
    observer.observe(section);
  });
};

checkForSections();
```

```css
* {  box-sizing: border-box;  padding: 0;  margin: 0;}.navbar {  position: fixed;  width: 100%;  padding: 2rem;  background-color: cornflowerblue;  display: flex;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;}.navbar__list {  list-style: none;  display: flex;}.navbar__item {  margin-left: 1rem;}.navbar__link,.navbar__link:visited {  color: inherit;  text-decoration: none;}.navbar__link:hover,.navbar__link:active,.navbar__link:visited:hover,.navbar__link:visited:active {  color: red;}section {  height: 100vh;  text-align: center;  padding: 5rem;  display: flex;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;}section h2 {  color: #bada55;  font-size: 5rem;}.highlight {  color: red;}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">  <ul class="navbar__list">    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="#home" class="navbar__link">Home</a></li>    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="#about" class="navbar__link">About</a></li>    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="#contact" class="navbar__link">Contacts</a></li>  </ul></nav><body>  <section id="home">    <h2>Home</h2>  </section>  <section id="about">    <h2>About</h2>  </section>  <section id="contact">    <h2>Contact</h2>  </section></body>
```

Comment: Hi Pilchard, thanks a lot! It works. If I understand it correctly the destructuring only checks for it ones while the foreach loop checks it al the time?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you have it right. The destructuring is the same as checking only the first entry in the array of entries `const [entry] = entries;` is the same as `const entry = entries[0];` and the `forEach` loop checks all the entries in the array every time.

Comment: Alright, that's wonderful. Thanks for your explanation and time. Have a nice day! :)